# How to Calculate the Cumulative week sales in qlikview?

Tags: qlikview

I want to calculate the cumulative week sales in qlikview, when I click in number of week for example 3, it calculated automatically 1+2+3, but id doesn't work.

Here my expression:

**Sum({=$(=vStart)<=$(vweek)"}>}aggr($(vNbOSales),NumSemaine))**

But when I specify the number it work like this: vweek =3

**Sum({=$(=vStart)<=3"}>}aggr($(vNbOSales),NumSemaine))**

thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all thank you EldadT for your help, I get the answer when you talk about what do I have in the variable.
 The answer is:`Count({$<TIME_KEY={"CURRENT"},NumSemaine={"<=$(=max(NumSemaine))"}>}` without douing sum before expression just add in set analysis 
thank you again EldadT 
And hope this help anybody else
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In cases like this, you have to **explicitly** assign the week numbers;
create a variable that holds ALL the week numbers till the week you choose, i.e for week 4 that variable `vWeeks` will look like `vWeeks = 1,2,3,4` and then use that variable in your expression

```
Sum({<Weeks = $(vWeeks)>}aggr($(vNbOSales),NumSemaine))
```

Comment: sum({<NumSemaine={<=$(vend)}>} aggr($(vNbOrder),NumSemaine)), this is my expression it working when vend=3 but when vend=variable that's not working! Help

Comment: what do you have in the variable?

Comment: in variable I have that: vNbOrder= Count({$<TIME_KEY={"CURRENT"}>} distinct ([Numero Commande]))